# MVVM design feels too unwieldy, am I doing it wrong?

Tags: c#, wpf, architecture, mvvm

I've recently started creating a WPF application, and am just hoping that someone can confirm to me that I'm building my overall system architecture properly, or correct me if I'm heading off in the wrong direction somewhere. Especially since I'm trying to do MVVM, there are a lot of layers involved, and I'm not sure I'm doing things properly.

Here's a simplified description of the system:

Data is stored in an SQL Server database, which is accessed through Linq to SQL. Let's say that the database contains two tables, `USERS` and `USER_GROUPS`. Each table has an auto-generated Linq to SQL class, `DB_USER` and `DB_USER_GROUP`.

Now in the application, I want to display a `ListBox` with each `ListBoxItem` containing various UI elements for displaying/modifying the users' info, which is done using a `DataTemplate`.

I have a view model class for the window, which uses a Linq to SQL query (joining the two tables) to populate an `ObservableCollection<User>` named `UserList`, which the `ListBox` in the window has bound as its `ItemsSource`. `User` is a class implementing `INotifyPropertyChanged` that handles all the formatting/getting/setting of database data into what's needed by the WPF controls. The section of code handling this is something like:

```
DBDataContext db = new DBDataContext();

var allUsers = from user in db.USERs
                   .Where(u => u.ENABLED == true)
               from group in db.USER_GROUPs
                   .Where(g => g.GROUPID == u.GROUPID)
                   .DefaultIfEmpty()
               select new { user, group };

foreach (var user in allUsers)
{
    User u = new User(db, user.user, user.group);
    UserList.Add(u);
}
```

So the `User` class is constructed with private properties for a `DB_USER`, a `DB_USER_GROUP`, and the database DataContext class. All of a `User`'s public properties basically wrap the relevant columns, with their `get` methods returning the values for WPF to use, and `set` changing the column(s) and then calling `SubmitChanges()` on the private DataContext property to update the database.

This is all working fine, but it feels a little unwieldy, so I'm just wondering if I've missed something that would make it cleaner. Specifically, storing a DataContext inside each element of `UserList` seems odd, but I wasn't sure of a better method to be able to update the database whenever data was changed in the UI.

Any feedback is appreciated, and please let me know if anything's unclear, I'm not sure how well I've explained it.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Starting off, let's put some labels on what you are doing here: `DB_USER` is your Model and `User` is your ViewModel (I 'd have preferred `UserViewModel` for the latter just so that it's more clear what's going on).

One thing that's immediately obvious is that it's not really proper for your ViewModel to have functionality suited to your Model, i.e. that `DataContext` does not belong where it currently is. This is a piece of information that should either be in your Model, or alternatively encapsulated in some `DataStore`/`DataService` (take your pick) class. Your ViewModel would then be responsible, when the time comes to save any changes, to tell the `DataStore` "here's an updated snapshot of this model, please save it for me" (this would most likely be exposed to the UI through an `ICommand`). This feels cleaner and underscores the idea that your ViewModel is a layer that adapts the realities of your model to your choice of UI.

Other than the above, there's nothing in what you describe that I feel needs to be "corrected". However, I can offer some suggestions regarding things that you have not elaborated on.

Exposing data from a Model through a ViewModel is always something that can be implemented in many ways. When considering what approach to take, you should take into account the possibility of the same Model being exposed through different Views at the same time. In this case, IMHO the preferred approach is to have a separate ViewModel for each View (the Views may well be of different types, so they could have different expectations from the ViewModel adapter thus pointing to multiple types of ViewModels as well), so you would need to use a pattern that allows changes to be communicated from one ViewModel to any others in "real time".

One way to do this would be to make your Models implement `INotifyPropertyChanged` themselves and have each ViewModel hook into its Model for notifications, so when a change occurs ViewModel A pushes the change to the Model, and the Model notifies ViewModel B.

However personally I don't like polluting my Models with what is in essence code that only caters to the needs of the UI, so another approach is needed. That would be making the `DataService` I mentioned above expose functionality (methods and events) through which ViewModel A can tell the service "hey, the Model I 'm wrapping has had some changes" ; note that this is different from "I want you to persist the current snapshot of this Model". ViewModel B has already hooked into a suitable "ModelChanged" event, so it gets notified and pulls the updated information from the service. This has the added benefit that if at any time the service detects that the backing data repository has been updated by a source external to the current process, there's a ready made mechanism to broadcast a "Calling all ViewModels: Model X has been updated, any interested parties please talk to me about learning the details" message.

Above all, always keep in mind that there is no "one true MVVM style" and there are myriads of possible approaches. Which one to take depends not only on hard facts and the current position of the slider on the YAGNI/HyperEngineering scale, but also on, dare I say, your *taste*.

Comment: Thanks, that gives me some things to consider. I think I may have over-simplified, but I do actually have a `UserViewModel`, that's what the code section in my post is inside. It also includes various other functionality related to the window that wasn't really relevant to my example. `User` is kind of a "sub-viewmodel", I suppose, an "in-between" class that mostly just wraps the data coming from the model, which seemed necessary mostly because I had data coming from two models that I needed to combine into one `ObservableCollection`. Should I be building this into the models directly instead?

Comment: @ChadBirch: Just have your ViewModels wrap as many Models as necessary for you to get the desired effect. You could have a `UserViewModel` and a `UserWithGroupViewModel` -- or you could decide that exposing just the information in a `User` model is not very helpful and have just one `UserViewModel` that exposes both `User` and `UserGroup`. Also, you can put `UserViewModel` itself in an `ObservableCollection`, I don't see anything wrong with that. I 've had e.g. a `DeviceGroupViewModel` that exposes an `ObservableCollection<DeviceViewModel>` in the past.

Answer (score 3):

Tricky question, and I can see why people aren't jumping all over themselves to answer—mainly because you aren't doing anything technically wrong. But since you ask, I'll tell you what I'd change to tighten up both MVVM (which you asked for) and the data acess (which you didn't).

The way I approach a ViewModel is as a wrapper for my underlying data model, rather than as an enhancement to my View. It *assists* the view by providing INotifyPropertyChanged and all that, but I try to make the ViewModel useful for whatever view it'll end up inside. That's the main difference, IMO, between MVC and MVVM. What you have is more of an MVC with your User object acting as a controller for the View.

Also, I'd probably do away with UserList and use the ListBox.ItemsSource to manage the list after binding it once. Actually, in WPF, I've gotten more used to having a CollectionViewSource and binding the UI controls to that. Makes it simpler to track selected items and adding to them and removing from them isn't too onerous.

For the data access, I wouldn't feed those into the object at all. Data access belongs in your model and persisting changes should be handled there. The .Net framework does a pretty good job with connection management, to the point where re-instantiation and teardown are the next best thing to costless. That allows you to keep things tight and wrap data connections in using clauses. If you really feel like you have to persist to the database on every property change, have your model subscribe to the PropertyChanged event—that's what it's there for, after all. :)

Answer (score 2):

Usually, I keep my models as dumb as possible (POCO). My viewmodel has the heavy logic of querying the database and setting its properties that are bound to the UI. In that layout, the viewmodel has a single instance of your DataContext and there is no need for it to be passed around inside of the models.

Answer (score 2):

I generally follow that approach with some differences, big surprise there :)  In larger projects I don't like to wrap or include my domain entities in my ViewModels.  This is something I carried over from the ASP.NET MVC in Action books where you map (AutoMapper) domain entities to display models before the view receives them.  Its nice when there is an impedance between the domain entity(s) and what needs to be displayed.

It also comes in handy when mocking up the screens, I can work from the screen backwards to the DisplayModel knowing I'll map what I need from the domain entity.  I'm big on my Views being blendable so a designer can open the View up and it looks pretty close to run time View.

So in some cases I'll have my entity models (User/UserGroup), my DisplayModel (User), and my ViewModel (UserViewModel).

As mentioned in other answers I tend to keep the data business out of the ViewModel.  I'll create a Repositiory or a service of some type and inject it into my ViewModels.  So in my ViewModel I might call `var user = UserRepository.GetUsers();`  and then map the results to my DisplayModel.  Or `UerRepository.InsertOrUpdate(user);` `UserRepository.Save();`

Unrelated, [AutoMapper](http://automapper.org/) is a great tool as well as [Caliburn Micro](http://caliburnmicro.codeplex.com/) or MVVM-Light.